# Serverless With Scrapy [ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError:

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, web-scraping, scrapy, serverless

I am trying to use aws lambda feature for deploying my serverless project as I wanted the scrapy cronjob to run every minute but I encountered following error.

```
ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'liveshare/spiders/livemarket': /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /var/task/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_openssl.abi3.so)
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

My folders structure is as follows I have no Idea why this error is occuring in server as sls offline in local is working fine.

```
|liveshare   
└───spiders
│   │__livemarket.py
│    
│_ __init__.py 
│_ items.py
│_ middlewares.py
│_ pipelines.py     
│_settings.py
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the wrong download of cryptography manylinux package. Try to change python runtime in lambda to `python3.8` or `python3.9`.

If the issue still persists you can use older versions of cryptography.